# Basic syntax - does class `merMod` include `glmerMod`?

Tags: r, syntax, glm, lme4

Quick and basic question:

I have run a generalised linear mixed effects model (glmm) using the `lme4` package. The class of the model is:

```
class(m1)
#[1] "glmerMod"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "lme4"
```

I would now like to use the `testFactors` function from the `phia` package. According to [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phia/phia.pdf), this function supports models of class `"lm", "glm", "mlm", "lme", and "mer" or "merMod" (excluding models fitted by nlmer)`.

Does this mean that my model's class is supported because it includes the suffix `merMod`, or does it explicitly have to say `glmerMod`? The function does run with my model but I just wanted to make sure it was appropriate.

Cheers

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114291/post-hoc-test-for-object-of-class-glmermod-in-r.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement you are right. Can you clarify if I can ascertain this in the future by assuming that the class `merMod` refers to any object whose class ends in `merMod`?